# Installing Ubuntu without a disk, using an external hard drive

Tags: package-management

The computer I have doesn't have a CD burner, but I do have an external hard drive.  I can't upgrade to the new Ubuntu. I got the older version off an old CD, have a player  not a burner, so I downloaded the newest version of Ubuntu.

It won't automatically run the program and the websites say I need to burn something to make it run. What do I do?  If anyone knows, please let me know.

Comment: Can you create a bootable USB?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by creating a "usb live boot" hard disk drive, from which you can boot and start the install process with ease.

The answers provided on these questions may be helpful for you to create the bootable hard disk drive for both Windows and Linux based OS's:

1. [How to create a Windows installation USB in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47362/how-to-create-a-live-usb-for-windows-in-ubuntu)
2. [How can I create a bootable USB disk from a CD image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30048/how-can-i-create-a-bootable-usb-disk-from-a-cd-image)
3. [How do you create a bootable USB stick using windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153171/how-do-you-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-using-windows-7)

Anyway I suggest you to use the Startup Disk Creator to perform this task in Linux. Unetbootin is also a good choice.

Good luck!