# Installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 UEFI/CSM problems

Tags: 12.04, uefi, ccsm

I am having problems installing Ubuntu. I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04.3 64 bit from this site (I have a Toshiba p850 i7, so it is a new laptop, that's why I chose 64 bit), and I mounted it on a USB using universal USB installer.

I tried booting from USB with UEFI on, but I got a black screen with GNU grub, and a grub command line. I tried rebooting but with UEFI off (CSM), it booted normally, but it didn't detect my Windows 8 operating system. I suppose that's because I booted with UEFI off. I need my PC to dual boot, so I want Ubuntu to be installed with UEFI on.

Comment: If you're referring to (eventually) existing questions and information, share your research with proper references and explanations why existing solutions don't work _or_ (much less preferred) remove the notion that those exist since users have to do this work for you instead or will (much more likely) downvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure that Universal USB Installer is the best tool for creating the USB drive. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153171/how-do-you-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-using-windows-7) question and answers cover the issue, so you may want to consult it. In Linux, `dd` works, and there are ports of `dd` to Windows, such as [`dd` for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) and [WinDD.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/windd/) I haven't tried either of those tools, so I can't promise either will work for you.

Second, the problem with the installer not "recognizing" Windows is deceptive. The installer is probably detecting the Windows partitions just fine, but isn't giving you the option to automatically resize and set up Linux next to them. In this case, you must use the (poorly-named) "Something Else" installation option, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302680/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-uefi-enabled-windows-8-on-a-dell-xps-8500) (among many other places). Note that some sites describe use of this option on BIOS-based computers, but one detail is different for EFI systems: You must create an [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and tell Ubuntu to use it by marking it as an "EFI boot partition."

Finally, if all else fails, it is possible to install Ubuntu in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and then install an [EFI boot loader for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) after the fact. [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is likely to be the easiest to install, although you may need to install an EFI filesystem driver for ext4fs to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

First check that your BIOS firmware version is up-to-date.  There was a known problem with older firmwares.  Don't let boot-repair rename the bootloaders, not necessary, and you might need the efi-boot menu to boot windows (bug 1091464).