# How can I create an bootable USB stick on Win7-32bit machine?

Tags: usb

How can I create an bootable USB stick on Win7-32bit machine ?

I have downloaded the ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso onto a USB stick.

As it is an ISO file, it will not boot on my laptop.

Thank You

Comment: If you have 32-bit Windows, you probably need 32-bit Ubuntu as well.

Comment: If system can run Windows 7, it probably is a 64 bit system, just crippled software. If you have 2GB or more of RAM then use 64 bit Ubuntu. In comment above, you have to use an installer that formats flash drive, extracts ISO and converts it to bootable device by installing a boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Try [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), it can make bootable flash from ISO image, or even download appropriate image (32b or 64b) from the internet.

Comment: I have found that asking for WIN7 is not the same as asking for windows.

Answer (score -1):

So the answer is "find" Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.5.exe.
The other "duplicate questions" do not link to any site that was useful.

Shame really.

Comment: If you're going to complain about the duplicate questions, at least read their answers first. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/153174/301745) also recommends PenDriveLinux Universal USB Installer.