# I would like help installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, skype

I have a Win10 HP Notebook with an Intel Pentium N3540 Processor and 4GB RAM on a 500GB HDD. I have been trying to get Ubuntu on my computer via a flash drive and so far I am unsuccessful. it seems like everytime I try to complete this process, I am missing something important and it just doesn't work. is there anybody out there willing to help me to do this? perhaps on skype with screen share? I need help, thank you.

Comment: Please read though [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) and [this guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi). If you have specific issues with a particular step in the process, let us know. As for getting an iso on a usb while in windows, read through [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/153171/how-do-you-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-using-windows-7) and use one of the suggested programs.

Comment: alright I have read through all the guides and to be honest I barely understand all of it. but I believe I got Ubuntu onto a usb using unetbootin, and now I cant figure out the uefi menu. everytime I select the flash drive on there and try to figure out how to boot, I hit a dead end. I swear nothing in these guides is at all like my computer and im becoming quite frustrated.  so can someone please ACTUALLY help? like live assistance? no more generic responses, please, I beg.

Comment: Only one generic response, and it was too much ;). Ok. Turn off fast boot in windows, go into your bios, and disable "safe boot". Select your usb to be the bootable device, and boot with the USB in. Let me know what happens after that.

Comment: thank you that really worked! i feel bad now haha... sorry for being a brat. thnks!

Comment: Glad it worked. I've moved my comment (more or less) to the answers section below. Please mark it as the correct answer if it solved your issue so others with the same issue can benefit from the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the program `unetbootin` (available on Windows). Burn the Ubuntu ISO to a flashdrive using `unetbootin`.

Turn off fast boot in Windows.

Turn off "save boot" in your bios, and change the bootable device to the flashdrive. Restart, and your flashdrive should be booting.

Install Ubuntu!