# How to install Ubuntu on Dell?

Tags: system-installation

I want to replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell computer.

What should I do?

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Linux-on-your-Windows/

Comment: @Sina I don't want to use Linux mint. And also i want only Ubuntu in my system no using virtual machine

Comment: Your question isn't clear! Do you want to replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu? do you want to have dual-boot (Win10/Ubuntu)? do you want to install Ubuntu Bash inside Windows10?

Comment: @Yaron yes i want to replace windows 10 with Ubuntu.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0)

Comment: @Yaron can you guide me for this ?

Comment: [this](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0) is a step by step guide for Installing Ubuntu (note that it will **replace** your current Windows10)

Answer (score 0):

**Here are 4 easy steps to install Ubuntu on your Dell machine.**

1. First configure your machine to boot from a USB drive, (in most cases that would be pressing F2 or F12 or Delete repeatedly) after the computer starts up until you see the BIOS screen.
2. Create a bootable USB drive. See [How do you create a bootable USB stick using windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153171/how-do-you-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-using-windows-7)
3. Boot your machine from the bootable USB drive
4. Once you boot from the USB drive, you can follow the prompts for installing Ubuntu. In your case I assume you want a clean install of Ubuntu, so choose the option to "Replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu".